# Manipulate matrix columns from concatenated name-strings using R's paste

Tags: r, matrix

I have a number of matrices (foo1, foo2, ...) with 10 columns of numerical data. I need to extract and manipulate specific columns from them, within a for loop in R. 
What I tried fails rather pityfully ...

```
> for (i in 1:10) {
    for (k in 1:4) {
      aver_foo <- mean(paste("foo",k,"[,i]",sep=""))
      do something
    }
  }

Warning message:
In mean.default(paste("foo", k, "[,i]", sep = "")) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

The idea was to create a name string to extract the i-th column value of the pertinent matrix based on loop index. I did check the documentation SO and Google, but Google does not deal well with the keyword "R" and I am obviously not understanding something basic. 
 Any help appreciated.

Comment: We can use `lapply(mget(ls(pattern="foo\\d+")), function(x) colMeans(x[1:4]))`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, but will you explain some of the logic you are suggesting ?

Comment: The logic is that `mget` returns the value i.e. matrices of all the `foo` objects in a `list` , loop over those with `lapply`, extract the first four columns and get the column means with `colMeans`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't take the mean of a string.  You need to use `get` to find the object with that name. To answer in the spirit of your original code:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    for (k in 1:4) {
      aver_foo <- mean(get(paste("foo",k, sep=""))[,i])
      do something
    }
}
```

but @akrun is right,  it might be better to use some form of apply, rather than a loop.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `lapply` and `colMeans`

```
lapply(mget(ls(pattern="foo\\d+")), function(x) colMeans(x[,1:4]))
```

Comment: Thanks for yr answer but as a beginner I favor @G5W's less complete but easier to understand answer. When I tries your answer it gives me an error:  `Error in colMeans(x[1:4]) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions ` followed by `Called from: colMeans(x[1:4])
Browse[1]> `

Comment: @Cbhihe  it's okay. My code is `colMeans(x[, 1:4])` and not `colMeans(x[1:4])`